# contextual filter author id

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-contextual-filters

Ok, so here's my problem. I feel it's really very simple and I am missing something. I have a Drupal 7 view which shows a certain type of content. Say it has a url `mysite.com/article`. What I want is, if the url is like `mysite.com/article/me`, it would load the articles posted by this current user. "me" will always be "me" and would not take any id/username.

Hope the problem is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the filter "Content: Author uid" in your contextual filter;
2. Check "Provide default value";
3. Select "User ID from logged in user".

And to distinct all articles with articles by author you need to create separated views/panels.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Find screenshot for contextual filter setting]

Use contextual filter as screenshot.

Comment: A detailed explanation [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102723/contextual-filter-by-author-id)